# Running DC over long distance

Tags: dc

I have a 3 conductor DC wind turbine pushing out 12VDC to a charge controller. Wire length about 90 feet and I believe 10AWG wire. (Realizing now that it should be thicker) Battery system is 12V and an inverter. The output on the inverter is 120VAC with 3 conductor 8AWG running a distance of about 90 feet as well. Output max on the inverter is 2000W and I will probably use close to 15A. I know there is definitely a voltage drop on both of those that may reduce performance. My question now, is if I were to move the inverter to the end of the 8AWG conductors what would I need to keep the voltage up over the long distance?

Comment: I think you would be better of moving inverter as close as possible to the wind turbine. You could then use a lot thinner cables to run to your load. This would be similar to how your electrical provider is supplying your house with electricity. They generate high voltage AC that can run long distances on thinner wires. Once those reaches your house the voltage gets stepped down to 115/220V.

Comment: You MUST install the inverter as close as possible to the batteries.  The manual for the 2000 watt inverter I have on my boat recommends two #4/0 cables if the inverter is 10 - 15 feet from the batteries.

Comment: Roughly how much current will you be pulling from the 12V battery with 15A of 120 VAC?  What's the resistance of 90' of 8AWG? Now do the math... (I get an unacceptable voltage drop.. what did you get?)

Answer (score 3):

Voltage drop across a resistance is proportional to current flowing though it, so you will have less loss to resistance for a higher voltage/lower current than for a lower voltage/higher current. This is why long distance power lines use the highest voltages possible.

In your case, sending 120 volts over your long run would be more efficient than sending 12 volts. Keep in mind that this assumes you have wiring that is rated to handle the new higher voltage between the turbine and the point of use for the 120 vac.

Interestingly, my solar system strings lots of 40 volt panels together in series to send up to 600 volts back to the inverter because otherwise I'd need massive cables to carry the same amount of power. The latest trend is to put micro inverters on every panel to convert the low voltage to high voltage as close to the generation point as possible to minimize wire size.